# NotificationListenerService tickerText is empty for some applications

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, notification-listener

I am trying to get data from notification that is created by my bank's app. I have created an app with Notification listener and this simple implementation, just to start, that should save a package name and TickerText for all notifications that are displayed on my phone.

```
@Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
        if (sbn.getNotification().tickerText != null)
            saveToFirebase(sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString(),sbn.getPackageName());
        else
            saveToFirebase("No text",sbn.getPackageName());

    }
```

I can see that for most of the apps notification text can be read from the tickerText, but for two bank's apps that I am using, tickerText is empty.

Does anyone know is there any way to get to this text? I can see that my Pebble can consume those notifications and display them on my watch so I assume that there must be some way to got it.

Comment: Yeah I'm getting the same issue. I've tried to get the tickerText from OutLook and Discord, and it `sbn.notification.tickerText`(Kotlin) is null. But if I go into accessibility services and turn on TalkBack, TalkBack is able to read notifications, so I don't know what tickerText actually does.